# How to use a boot() in laravel model?

Tags: laravel, events, model, laravel-events

I have two models and migration tables named as `users` and `roles` (for both migrations and models names).

This is the first time I am using `boot()`. I have one doubt: if the user is successfully registered then his role should be stored automatically in the `roles` table as admin, for that please help me I am trying some ways it's not working.

`User.php`

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Static::updating(function (){});
    // Here I am unable to figure out how to pass roles model or migration take data and how to update the values
}
```

`create_roles_table.php`

```php
$table->string('role');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foriegn('user_id')->references ('id')->on('users');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many users can be 'admin', yes? Then the `roles` table should have the following structure.

```php
// create_roles_table
$table->id();
$table->string('role'); // Admin, Manager, etc
$table->timestamps();
```

If an user can only have one role, then the `users` table should have a foreign key to the `roles` table.

```php
// create_users_table
$table->id();
// other fields
$table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained('roles', 'id'); // equivalent to $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id'); $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
```

---

When an user is registered, laravel fires the event [`Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#events).

You can listen to it in your `App/Providers/EventServiceProvider` class.

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Will fire every time an User registers
        Event::listen(function (Registered $event) {
            $event->user->forceFill(['role_id' => ADMIN_ROLE_ID])->save();
        });
    }
}
```

---

If you want to use the User Model's events instead, it should look like this:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // Will fire everytime an User is created
        static::creating(function (User $user) {
            $user->forceFill(['role_id' => ADMIN_ROLE_ID])->save();
        });
    }
}
```

or using `booted()` instead

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public static function booted()
    {
        // Will fire every time an User is created
        static::creating(function ($user) {
            $user->forceFill(['role_id' => ADMIN_ROLE_ID])->save();
        });
    }
}
```

---

If an user can have many roles, a separate migration is needed. `role_id` no longer needs to be on the `users` table.

```php
// create_role_user_table
$table->id()
$table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained('roles', 'id');
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users', 'id');
```

Then you need to define a relationship in both `User` and `Role` models

```php
// User
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

```php
// Role
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

As for updating the role when creating/registering an user an user, replace

```
user->forceFill(['role_id' => ADMIN_ROLE_ID])->save()
```

by

```
user->roles()->attach(ADMIN_ROLE_ID);
```

Comment: Yes ,many users can admin .when an user registers the role should be stored in roles table right when I use boot() method

Comment: How the migrations look if the user have many roles

Comment: The relationship turns into M:N. You need a separate pivot table (role_user: id, role_id, user_id) instead of using role_id in users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and great explanation 